# API - Error 202 "Your credentials do not allow access to this resource"

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter, pyrocms

I am trying to use `account/verify_credentials` and `statuses/update` with the Twitter API. I always get an *error 202*, please see error returned below:

> {"errors":[{"code":220,"message":"Your credentials do not allow access
> to this resource."}]}

Answer (score 4):

Double check your code - it looks like, that you're calling the Twitter REST API with an application-token, instead of an user-token.

Have a look here:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth

To be able to successfully creating a new status for an user, you need a specific user-access token.

Comment: Above url not working, new url https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/application-only.html

Comment: me also got the same error "220, Your credentials do not allow access to this resource". I'm using oauth2/token api to generate access token for this I set grant_type=client_credentials and Authorization. Now I'm getting Accesstoken successfully. But when use statuses/home_timeline.json it's getting error. Can you please clarify what steps I need to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your keys were created with the correct permissions. You can check this in the "Keys and tokens" section of your Twitter developer dashboard: [Image of Keys and tokens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRHAV.png%5BKeys)