# message - Your credentials do not allow access to this resource. code - 220

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

This question has been asked numerous times but I have not found any solutions. In my application the user tweets a message and picture.  Up until the past few days there have been no issues in relation to this.

However in the past few days I have been getting this error:

> D/Twitter Update Error﹕ 403:The request is understood, but it has been
>   refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is
>   used when requests are being denied due to update limits
>   (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following).
>       message - Your credentials do not allow access to this resource.
>       code - 220

I have been testing the app a lot but I don't thinks it's possible I exceeded any limits.  I notice a lot of posts have gone up recently about this.  Does anyone have any solution on this?  or even any information.

Thanks

Comment: Have you got the solution?

Comment: @micky apologies, I should've come back and posted.  It turns out that this was an issue within my own code.  I was encountering the issue when the app tweeted on the user's behalf.  So my issue was on Login with twitter I stored the access token and access token secret in my shared preferences.  From when it was working to when the issue arose I had reformatted my code and after a lot of scanning lines of code it turned out I had made changes to my shared preferences, so when the app tried to tweet the access token/secret were null so essentially I had no credentials!  I hope this might help?

Comment: Thanks DJ-DOO I too had mistake in my sharedpreferences...thanks

Comment: Great!! Glad I could help...maybe upvote my comment if it helped!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [API - Error 202 "Your credentials do not allow access to this resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23195832/api-error-202-your-credentials-do-not-allow-access-to-this-resource)